# How to add non word characters to Inflector::slug() for CakePHP 1.2?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

The CakePHP 1.2 Inflector class has a slug() method that converts spaces to underscores, converts accented characters to non-accented characters and non word characters are removed.

I have a case where special doubled quotes [“ and ”] are not getting removed.

I can see the line where I need to place the characters for the quotes, but I don't know what tool to use to put the characters in to a format where they will be recognised correctly. (i.e. â€™ is a special single quote that gets converted to a space and ultimately removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My eventual work around was to use the Encoding feature in Chrome to get the characters I needed.  Normally, the web page has the UTF-8 charset, so I forced Chrome to display in ISO-8859-1, which transformed “ in to â€œ.  It's Menu, Tools, Encoding and then select the encoding.

When it came to actually altering Inflector::slug(), the `'/[^\w\s]/' => ' ',` line is changed to `'/â€“|â€œ|â€™|â€|[^\w\s]/' => ' ',`.

I've made sure to convert [^\w\s] last, and â€ second last.  If [^\w\s] is earlier, then € gets converted to a space, and other special characters using that don't get converted.  And there's a similar deal with â€.

The replacement string used is not exhaustive.  Currently it caters for a special dash, special inverted double quote, special double quote and special single quote.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove non-ascii characters before pusing it into the inflector.

```
<?php $output = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $input); ?>
```

Comment: I could, but I think the characters that a special unicode character get transformed in to are made of ascii and non-ascii characters.  One of the issues with the default implementation of using /[^\w\s]/ to is that the € from â€™ gets stripped, leaving the rest of the characters as valid word characters.